# Will the "Sub" claim in an Auth0 JWT always be unique?

Tags: jwt, auth0

I just have a quick Auth0 question. I've looked all over, but the more I look the more confused I get.

In the payload of the JWT that Auth0 gives me when I log in there is a Sub claim that look like this "sub": "facebook|123456789".

I'm just curious if sub will always be unique and if I can use it as a sort of foreign key in my database to link users to different tables.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The sub, short for subject, in this case is the User Id for the normalised user profile representing the user in Auth0.

Here, **facebook|123456789** is the connection strategy (social connection of type **facebook** in your example) piped with the **facebook ID** for the user (which came from facebook). However, bear in mind, that with **facebook**, when you set up a Connection, you are actually setting up connection to a particular Facebook App - (the App ID and App Secret that you configure in Auth0 for that connection strategy). Long story short, for a single connection strategy of type facebook, defined under social connections in Auth0 Dashboard - then yes, this would be unique and could be a correlating identifier to a separate datastore with enriched info about that user profile etc.

Just bear in mind, if you were to create another separate App defined in Facebook, then setup a new Auth0 facebook connection to that facebook app, and login with same user - they would almost certainly receive a different **sub** since the facebook userId would be different. For example, it might be **facebook|987654321** etc

Comment: So, if username "testuser" authenticates with my REST API, the returned JWT token "sub" claim should be sub=usertest?  From what I read, that is what sub claim should be.